# Addition with Rust and Webassembly

Tags: rust, webassembly

**Given** I want to sum the first n terms of a series *1,2,3,..* with the following function in Rust

```
fn sum_sequence(x: u64) -> u64 
{
    let mut s: u64 = 0;

    for n in 1..=x
    {
        s = s + n;
    }
    return s;
}
```

**When** I compile it for x64 architecture

```
cargo build --release
```

and run it with `x=10000000000` the result is `13106511857580896768` - fine.

**But** when I compile this very function to Webassembly (WASM)

```
cargo build --target wasm32-unknown-unknown --release
```

and run it with the same argument as before, `x=10000000000`,

```
wasmtime ./target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/sum_it.wasm --invoke sum_sequence 1000000000
```

**Then** the result is `-5340232216128654848`.

I would not have expected any deviation in results between Rust being compiled to x64 in comparison to Rust being compiled to WASM. Also, from the WASM text file (below), I do not see why I should get a negative result when I run it with WASM.

How does it come that WASM shows a different result and what can I do do correct the calculation of WASM?

```
(module
  (type (;0;) (func (param i64) (result i64)))
  (func $sum_sequence (type 0) (param i64) (result i64)
    (local i64 i64 i32)
    block  ;; label = @1
      local.get 0
      i64.eqz
      i32.eqz
      br_if 0 (;@1;)
      i64.const 0
      return
    end
    i64.const 1
    local.set 1
    i64.const 0
    local.set 2
    block  ;; label = @1
      loop  ;; label = @2
        local.get 1
        local.get 2
        i64.add
        local.set 2
        local.get 1
        local.get 1
        local.get 0
        i64.lt_u
        local.tee 3
        i64.extend_i32_u
        i64.add
        local.tee 1
        local.get 0
        i64.gt_u
        br_if 1 (;@1;)
        local.get 3
        br_if 0 (;@2;)
      end
    end
    local.get 2)
  (table (;0;) 1 1 funcref)
  (memory (;0;) 16)
  (global (;0;) (mut i32) (i32.const 1048576))
  (global (;1;) i32 (i32.const 1048576))
  (global (;2;) i32 (i32.const 1048576))
  (export "memory" (memory 0))
  (export "sum" (func $sum))
  (export "__data_end" (global 1))
  (export "__heap_base" (global 2)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems to be because wasm does not support native `u64` as a [type](https://github.com/WebAssembly/spec/tree/master/interpreter#s-expression-syntax), only the signed variants (notably, `i64`), which is why it's using `i64` as the type for the arithmetic operations. Since this then overflows a 64-bit integer (the correct output is `n * (n+1) / 2`, or `50000000005000000000`, you're getting a negative value due to the overflow, which is then getting printed to console. This is due to a lack of type support in wasm.

Just for reference, a `Σ n=0 to N := (N * (N+1) / 2`, which I use from here on out since it's much faster computationally, and correct for our purposes.

The result, `50000000005000000000`, takes ~65.4 bits in memory to accurately represent in memory, which is why you get wrapping behavior for x86_64 and wasm, just the types it wraps to are different.

Using NumPy, we can clearly confirm this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.uint64(10000000000)
>>> b = np.uint64(10000000001)
>>> (a >> np.uint64(1)) * b
13106511857580896768

>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.int64(10000000000)
>>> b = np.int64(10000000001)
>>> (a >> np.int64(1)) * b
-5340232216128654848
```

The values you are getting are due to unsigned and signed (two's complement) integer overflow. (Note: I'm using a right bitshift to simulate division-by-two, I could probably also use the `//` operator).

EDIT: Also, a good point was raised in the comments by Herohtar: it clearly overflows if run in debug mode, panicking with `'attempt to add with overflow'`.

Comment: You can also see that the Rust x64 version is overflowing if you run in debug which does checked arithmetic, as it will eventually panic with `'attempt to add with overflow'`